# Websphere v 6.1 server issue

Tags: websphere

When i am starting my local empty server (WebSphere v6.1 Server @ localhost), am getting below exception in the next few seconds and after that server starts up aborted automaticaly.

B A T C H R E C U R S I O N exceeds STACK limits ******

Recursion Count=1240, Stack Usage=90 percent

B A T C H PROCESSING IS A B O R T E D ******

Other that this nothing displayed in console.

Note: I try to start only empty server (no project is added)

Can anyone please help on this?

Much appreciated your help!!!

Comment: I would try to restart the computer...maybe there is something hooked. Otherwise you would have to reinstall the server maybe.

Comment: I have tried both the things but still am getting the same issue only no luck. Thanks for your update...

Comment: Hi, reg reinstall server - whether u r meaning to create new server with new profile or reinstalling the IBM webspher v 6.1 server itself?

Comment: I am thinking at reinstalling the IBM Websphere server. Of course, maybe you thought at this as the last thing to do, but I see no other option.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is specific for the command prompt.
You probably are starting the WebSphere form a custom `.bat` file where there's a subroutine that calls itself. So check the way you are starting the server.

You can achieve the same output with this:

```
@echo off
call :test
exit /b

:test
call :test
exit /b
```

Also check this -> [how to start WebLogic in Jdeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316426/how-to-start-weblogic-in-jdeveloper)