# how to start WebLogic in Jdeveloper

Tags: jdeveloper

I have just installed Jdeveloper and trying to start weblogic server using steps given at oracle site.

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/INFIN/create_domain.htm#INFIN292

I haven't imported any project but once I try to start the integrated server, I am getting below error:

******  B A T C H   R E C U R S I O N  exceeds STACK limits ******
Recursion Count=329, Stack Usage=90 percent
******       B A T C H   PROCESSING IS   A B O R T E D      ******

wondering where it is getting recursion as I do not have any project imported in Jdeveloper.

Comment: I have tried the command prompt mode to configure the web logic domain by running %Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\configure.cmd, but as soon as I run the bat file I get the above error, not sure what is wrong I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic Integrated server start from JDeveloper is highly dependent on class path you have in System as well user variable. After Debugging for 1 day I have got the solution. In my user variable I have something like

```
CLASSPATH=.;%CLASSPATH%;C:\JUNIT\junit-4.10.jar
```

Also make sure that in your system path there must not be any double quotes(") that will give you another error

File was not expected at this moment

So in case you are facing any problem with your web logic start as Integrated server, please cross check your class path. I did my delete and trial approach and finally it worked for me !!!!!!!!!!!!!